# What are all the finite transitive sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In set theory, we come across the definition of an ordinal as a well-ordered transitive set. And then we show that $\omega$ and all its elements are ordinals.

My question whether there are finite transitive sets which are not ordinals. Also, whether we know all the finite transitive sets.

Comment: An answer mentions the hereditarily finite sets. It may perhaps be useful to add that these are precisely the elements of $V_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n$ where $V_0=\emptyset$ and $V_{n+1}=\mathcal P(V_n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: There has been some recent attention given to (combinatorial and graph theoretic properties of) these sets. Note, for instance, that $V_\omega=\bigcup_n A_n$, where $A_0=\{\emptyset\}$, and $A_{n+1}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{x\cup\{y\}\mid x,y\in A_n\}$. If you let $a_n=|A_n|$, the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ is $1,2,4,12,112,11680,\dots$ You can find some work on it and related references in *Enumeration of the adjunctive hierarchy of hereditarily finite sets*, by Audrito, Tomescu, and Wagner, J Logic Computation (2015) 25 (3): 943-963.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are finite transitive sets which are not ordinals. For example, take $X = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

You can check quickly that $X$ is transitive, but it is not an ordinal, since it is not linearly ordered under $\in$. We have $\emptyset\not\in \{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\not\in\emptyset$. Of course, the only ordinal of size $3$ is $3 = \{0,1,2\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

As for your second question, every set has a [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure), and the transitive closure of $X$ is finite if and only if $X$ is [hereditarily finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set). So the finite transitive sets are exactly the transitive closures of hereditarily finite sets. I don't think you're going to find a more concrete characterization than that, unfortunately.

Comment: However, come to think of it, other characterizations might be very interesting. It seems combinatorists haven't paid them much attention but perhaps they should.

Comment: @BrianO See [OEIS sequence A001192](https://oeis.org/A001192).

Comment: @bof - Thanks, I was ignorant.

Comment: Anent the last sentence of the question, "whether we know all the finite transitive sets." Yes, in the sense that they are in one-to-one correspondence with the finite extensional acyclic digraphs, i.e., the finite acyclic digraphs with the property that distinct vertices have distinct out-neighborhoods.